# Evaluation Metrics in Pyspark

Tags: pyspark, metrics, evaluation

How can I perform Evaluation Metrics in Pyspark? I follow this [example](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/mllib-evaluation-metrics.html#multiclass-classification) available in Spark Doc but an error occurred. I want to evaluate a number of ML algorithms according to F1 score, accuracy and confusion matrix.

The error:

```
    File "C:\apps\spark-3.2.0-bin- 
    hadoop3.2\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 481, in 
    main RuntimeError: Python in worker has different version 3.9 than 
    that in driver 3.8, PySpark cannot run with different minor 
    versions. Please check environment variables PYSPARK_PYTHON and  
    PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON are correctly set.
```

Comment: Did you already try to update your ``pyspark`` version?

Comment: I use 3.2.0 version (Spark) and use Anaconda & Jupyter Notebook.

Comment: The error says your python version doesnt match with you pyspark version

Comment: Python version is 3.9. & Spark 3.2.0. What should I do?